# jQuery animate("left") not showing images until full width in sight

Tags: jquery, image, visible, marquee

I'm building a very tailored image scroller that uses animate("left") to get a marquee-like effect displaying a series of <div>s with nested images scrolling left. They are within a <div role="clip"> with "width: 960px; overflow: hidden;". The images use "position: absolute;" and z-index so that when the user uses mouseover, the gray image on top will fade and reveal the color image.

Each div will look like this:

```
<div class="showcase">
  <a href="#" class="showcase">
    <img src="images/clients/aria_gray.png" alt="" />
  </a>
  <img src="images/clients/aria_color.png" width="160" class="scbg" alt="Aria" />
</div>
```

The CSS specific to this code:

```
div.showcase {
  display: inline;
  width: /* calculated by a jQuery function */
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
a.showcase img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
img.scbg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

**The problem**: Images that are scrolling in do not appear *at all* until their full width is within the <div role="clip">.

I've tried searching Google, Blekko, jQuery API, and the suggested links but I think I'm using the wrong terminology to describe my problem.

I ♥ Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem or not but you are missing a semicolon after your `width` property in the `div.showcase` selector.